# How to set "withCredential Option" in Forge Viewer3D?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using viewer3D at my on premises environment.

So I had download all model files locally.

URL for viewer is

`https://www.company.com/viewer3D.html`

URL for models are

`https://model.company.com/some-model-files...`

Then, the viewer requests models by CORS XHR Request.

With this request, I want send COOKIE.

So I have to set `withCredentials = true`

Is there a way to set `withCredentials = true` in the viewer?

Comment: Don't understand a word of what you are asking here :(

Comment: @philippe-leefsma

Sorry for bad English.
I fixed the sentence.
Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API that lets you control that setting. It is in the source of the viewer.

One workaround would be to grab all the files of the viewer SDK and modify the source, then use the modified version in your application.

The source of the viewer SDK is not directly accessible, unless you download *manually* all the required files for a specific version. Alternatively you can PM me and will send you by email a zip with all required resources for the current version: philippe.leefsma"at"autodesk.com.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try!